# Hide inactive dates from datetime X-Axis

Tags: highcharts

I have created fiddle to show my current graph:
http://jsfiddle.net/LLExL/4445/

The code is

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        backgroundColor: 'none',
        spacingRight: 20,
        zoomType: 'x'
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    exporting: {
        enabled: false
    },
    legend: {
        borderWidth: 0,
        enabled: true,
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 25
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            animation: false,
            marker: {
                enabled: false,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: true,
                        radius: 5
                    }
                }
            }
        },
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Points'
    },
    tooltip: {
        shared: true
    },
    xAxis: {
        labels: {
            format: '{value: %d/%m}'
        },
        type: 'datetime'
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        showFirstLabel: true
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'column',
        name: 'Reached',
        data: [
            [1427328000000, 198],
            [1427414400000, 127],
            [1427673600000, 104],
            [1427760000000, 107],
            [1427846400000, 102],
            [1427932800000, 1],
            [1428278400000, 1],
            [1428364800000, 55],
            [1428451200000, 83],
            [1428537600000, 77],
            [1428624000000, 107],
            [1428883200000, 99],
            [1428969600000, 140],
            [1429056000000, 134],
            [1429142400000, 108],
            [1429228800000, 104],
            [1429488000000, 113],
            [1429574400000, 115],
            [1429660800000, 115],
            [1429747200000, 97],
        ]
    }, {
        type: 'line',
        name: 'Target',
        color: 'red',
        lineWidth: 2,
        data: [
            [1427328000000, 123],
            [1427414400000, 123],
            [1427673600000, 123],
            [1427760000000, 123],
            [1427846400000, 143],
            [1427932800000, 0],
            [1428278400000, 0],
            [1428364800000, 143],
            [1428451200000, 143],
            [1428537600000, 143],
            [1428624000000, 114],
            [1428883200000, 143],
            [1428969600000, 143],
            [1429056000000, 143],
            [1429142400000, 143],
            [1429228800000, 114],
            [1429488000000, 143],
            [1429574400000, 143],
            [1429660800000, 143],
            [1429747200000, 143],
        ]
    } ]
});
```

I want to remove inactive dates from the X-axis, ex. the dates BETWEEN 02/04 and 06/04 (but not these 2, since they have a value).

The only solution I have found working is to declare the dates myself via Categories and then going away from the datetime type axis. This is not the right solution for me tho, since the axis then won't fit correctly on smaller screens.

Is this anyhow possible to remove no-value-dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Highcharts there is no ordinal option for axis, but it can be set if you are using Highstock. This options hides values from x axis that do not have points.

You could use Highstock to create Highcharts chart with axis that have ordinal x axis.

Load Highstock JS file instead of Highcharts:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
```

In axis options set ordinal to true:

```
xAxis: {
        ordinal: true,
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LLExL/4451/

Comment: The problem is the data isn't included in the chart at all. But the chart shows the dates because of the "timeline" from 26/03 to 23/04

Comment: @Behrens I see that I have misunderstood your question - please see corrected answer.